# Fancybox outputting as 'document' type

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox-3

I'm currently using Fancybox 3 and everything seems to be working well though my browser (Chrome) seems to be interpreting my images as 'documents' thus rendering a white background. So I've followed the documentation to change the type to 'image' type. Though my code below does not work.

**Console Error**

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/png: "http://localhost/site.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/img_1.png".
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="fancybox" data-fancybox="gallery"  href=" '. $image_url .' ">
  <img src=" '. $image_url .' ">
</a>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  jQuery.fancybox.open({
      src  : '#fancybox',
      type : 'image'
    });
});
```

I've has to change all instances of `$` to `jQuery` as this is a requirement for Wordpress.

[This is the documentation I am following](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding `data-type="image"` to your links would be sufficient. Anyway, I could not understand from your description what exactly is your question/issue.

But I noticed that you have:

```
href=" '. $image_url .' "
```

See extra spaces around url? It should be:

```
href="'. $image_url .'"
```

And same for thumbnail image.

Comment: Thanks, @janis! This seemed to work. I did not see this solution in your documentation though I'm sure it's there somewhere.

Comment: Hmm, I was quite sure it is there, but looks like I missed it :) Anyway, next week I`ll start working on documentation for v3.1, you can preview it here - http://codepen.io/fancyapps/full/LyNXqr/

Comment: Awesome! Taking a look now. Thanks again